# Javascript loop through an array searching for characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of string values. I'd like to loop through the array and return any values that not only match the string values, but contain the values.What would be the best approach to this?

Here is what I have so far, which is searching for the exact value.

I'm using this logic is several places to match the url. For part of the site getLocation returns /about, /services, etc...
There is also an admin part which returns /adminabout, /adminservices, etc.

```
var getLocation = $location.$$path;
var isCustom    = ['about', 'services', 'volunteer', 'contact', 'give', 'blog'];

if(!isCustom.indexOf(getLocation) == -1){ 
  $scope.isCustom = true || false;  
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I've added some additional info

Comment: I am sorry, its really not clear to me what exactly you are trying to do. What do you expect to happen after this code is executed?

Comment: If `getLocation` contains the slash, then it will never match any of those objects.

Comment: You'll need to use regEx `.test` method to see if the location.path is an exact match OR contained in the isCustom values

Comment: `= false || true` - Delightful! You should read it aloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a filter to get the matched elements which doesn't contain the getLocation value.

```
var getLocation = $location.$$path.replace('/','');
var isCustom    = ['about', 'services', 'volunteer', 'contact', 'give', 'blog'];

var matchedResult = isCustom.filter(function(value) {
    return value.indexOf(getLocation) < 0
});
```

As question somewhat not clear, I assume you're trying to find if a string is present in the array item.

```
var getLocation =$location.$$path.replace('/', ''); // assuming it to be admin
var isCustom = ["/adminabout","adminservices","about","services"]


// matches if the string is present in any part of the array item
var matchedResult = isCustom.filter(function(value) {
    return value.indexOf(getLocation) !== -1
});

console.log(matchedResult); //["/adminabout", "adminservices"]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to loop over each item and see if it contains that value. Similar to string.contains?

Comment: that's what we are doing currently. We are loopng through each item and checking if it contains the string

Comment: This works well, except in my case the getlocation variable is going to be '/adminabout', with isCustom containing values like 'admin'. I've posted the answer that worked for me.

Comment: You just need to replace / initially before checking.

Comment: I would still prefer filter instead of manually looping through and pushing.

Comment: I've updated it in my answer. Now check length of matchedResult array and set the flag to true or false

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that matches whether or not the values in the `isCustom` value is contained in the `getLocation` value.

```
var searchThroughArray = (function (getLocation) {
var log = [];  
angular.forEach(isCustom, function(item, key) {
      var getLocation = $location.$$path.replace('/', '');
      if(getLocation.contains(item) == true){
        this.push(item);
    }
}, log);
if (0 < log.length){ 
    return true;
};
})();


if(searchThroughArray){
  $scope.isCustom = true; 
}else{
  $scope.isCustom = false; 
};
```